# Order of precedence with nested ternary operators

Tags: php, operators

I was in class the other day and this snippet of code was presented:

```
 <?php
 //Intialize the input
 $score=rand(50,100);
 //Determine the Grade
 $grade=($score>=90)?'A':(
 ($score>=80)?'B':(
 ($score>=70)?'C':(
 ($score>=60)?'D':'F')));
 //Output the Results
 echo "<h1>A score of $score = $grade</h1>";
 ?>
```

At the time I questioned the order of operations within the nested ternary operators, thinking that they would evaluate from the inside out, that is it would evaluate if $score were >= 60 first, then if $score >= 70, etc -- working through the whole stack every time regardless of the score.

To me it seems that this construct should follow the same order of precedence given to mathematical operators -- resolving the inner-most set of parentheses first and then working out, unless there is some order of operations unique to the ternary.

Unfortunately the discussion in class quickly became about winning an argument, when I really just wanted to understand how it works. So my questions are two:

(1)How would this statement me interpreted and why?

and

(2)Is the some sort of stack trace or step through tool that would allow me to watch how this code executes?

Comment: This is trivially easy to test for yourself.

Comment: Only trivial to those who know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP respects brackets. Expressions inside the innermost `( ... )` are evaluated first, like we are taught in elementary school.

PHP is unusual in that ternary operators are [left-associative](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30). This means without brackets, the ternary expression is evaluated left to right.

But in this particular case, the brackets force the expression to be evaluated right to left. This code is equivalent to:

```
if ($score >= 90) {
    $grade = 'A';
}
elseif ($score >= 80) {
    $grade = 'B';
}
elseif ($score >= 70) {
    $grade = 'C';
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is left associative, but with brackets applied, it evaluates right to left.

You might use `xdebug` or `phpdbg` as a step debugger to step through your code and see how it evaluates.

There is also VulcanLogicDumper around, which shows the instructions:

**http://3v4l.org/QeF9i/vld#tabs** compared to an if-elseif-else structure **http://3v4l.org/bZE6M/vld#tabs**

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   SEND_VAL                                                 50
         1      SEND_VAL                                                 100
         2      DO_FCALL                                      2  $0      'rand'
         3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $0
   5     4      IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL                              ~2      90, !0
         5    > JMPZ                                                     ~2, ->8
         6  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~3      'A'
         7    > JMP                                                      ->24
   6     8  >   IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL                              ~4      80, !0
         9    > JMPZ                                                     ~4, ->12
        10  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~5      'B'
        11    > JMP                                                      ->23
   7    12  >   IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL                              ~6      70, !0
        13    > JMPZ                                                     ~6, ->16
        14  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~7      'C'
        15    > JMP                                                      ->22
   8    16  >   IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL                              ~8      60, !0
        17    > JMPZ                                                     ~8, ->20
        18  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~9      'D'
        19    > JMP                                                      ->21
        20  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~9      'F'
        21  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~7      ~9
        22  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~5      ~7
        23  >   QM_ASSIGN                                        ~3      ~5
        24  >   ASSIGN                                                   !1, ~3
  10    25      ADD_STRING                                       ~11     '%3Ch1%3EA+score+of+'
        26      ADD_VAR                                          ~11     ~11, !0
        27      ADD_STRING                                       ~11     ~11, '+%3D+'
        28      ADD_VAR                                          ~11     ~11, !1
        29      ADD_STRING                                       ~11     ~11, '%3C%2Fh1%3E'
        30      ECHO                                                     ~11
        31    > RETURN                                                   1
```

**[How to read these Opcodes](http://rancoud.com/read-phps-opcode/)**

I will try to explain the first JMPZ in the opcode, in order to understand how it evaluates:

Of interest is Line 5, Opcode Number 5:

`5    > JMPZ                                                     ~2, ->8`

This means: If compare with 90 (opcode 4) is false, then JUMP to Opcode 8.

Warning: `->8` doesn't mean jump to Line 8.

Now, what is Opcode 8? The comparison with 80

`6     8  >   IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL                              ~4      80, !0`

And now it's safe to say that this doesn't evaluate, like you expected from inside out (90->60->70), but like an if-elseif-else structure (90->80->70).

Comment: Thank you Jens-Andre.  I tried in vain to get xdebug to work on NetBeans.  I've now moved over to SublimeText2 for many reasons.  What IDE are you using to produce this report?  Cheers!

Comment: The report shown here isn't produced by an IDE, it's produced by http://3v4l.org/ - Tab "VLD opcodes". If you want to do this on your own machine, you might try the VLD extension: http://pecl.php.net/package/vld . There are lot's of tutorials around, explaining how to marry xdebug with Netbeans. Maybe this is of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbJOP0YcSjs

Comment: Thanks for that bit about associativity, with that I was able to find this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence
Which answers the question I was about to ask, which was "what is the answer to (true ? false : false ? true : true)  and why?"   stacked ternary operators are processed  in the opposite order to the most others, especially the arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator short-circuits. Only the appropriate operand is evaluated. This means that the parens do not matter until they are actually tested.

```
echo false ? (crash() / 0) : "Worked.";
```

Comment: Thanks for the debug recommendation, Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

ternary are left to right:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

So it will evaluate what is to the left of the ? and based on that, evaluate either the 1st or 2nd side of the :.

You could put in a function call that has a side effect to demonstrate this:

```
function p($a,$b) { echo $a . " >= " . $b;  return $a>=$b; }
$grade=(p($score,90))?'A':(
 p($score,80)?'B':(
 p($score,70)?'C':(
 p($score,60)?'D':'F')));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but according to Rob and his link the ternary is actually right to left once it analyzes the statement left of the question mark.  I like the idea of inserting a function call into the ternary to cause it to report.  I didn't realize you could do that sort of thing. Cheers.